# Añadir imagen svg por CSS

Tags: css, svg

Bueno como dice el titulo necesito añadir una imagen svg al fondo de un div. La imagen he de añadirla por css si o si.

css

```
.catalogo-gallery .btn-pdf
{
   font-size: 17px;
   font-weight: 800;
   font-family: "Open Sans";
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   padding: 12px 50px;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-image: url("image.svg");
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

html

```
 <div class="div-btn" >
   <a style="color:'.$color.'; border-color:'.$color.';" class="btn-pdf" href="'.$tipo_catalogo["pdf"]["url"].'">DESCARGAR</a>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ponernos algo del código con el que estás tratando de poner la imagen de fondo? El **HTML** del **div** y el **CSS** que tratas de aplicar estaría bien para empezar.

Comment: @PHPMyguel listo,  el svg debe ir al lado de DESCARGAR, el svg es el icono de pdf

Comment: No me queda claro una cosa. ¿Quieres la imagen de **background** o que salga al lado de la palabra "DESCARGAR"? Porque de ser lo segundo ya tendrías que añadir una etiqueta **<img>** y no un **background-image**

Comment: los botones de descarga cambian de color, el svg que añadde debe poder cambiar de color. Con img se puede hacer eso?

Comment: No que yo sepa, pero podrías tener dos svgs ,uno de cada color y cambiarlo según tu necesidad. ¿En que circunstancia  tendría que cambiar el color? ¿Al hacer click en algún lado? ¿Al pasar el ratón por encima?

Comment: @PHPMyguel son categorias de productos que cada una tiene un color asignado y aparece el boton de descarga del color asignado. Asi que el svg debe cambiar de color con ese asignado. El cliente puede tener 1 o 100 categorias, poner 100 scg de 100 colores no es opcion. Debe ser automatizado

Comment: El color del svg en sí no lo puedes cambiar con **CSS**. ¿Es por eso por lo que tratas de cambiar el color de fondo de su contenedor?

Comment: No, el background-color ahora que lo dices es redundante, no hace falta

Comment: No conozco ninguna manera para cambiarle el color a una imagen mediante **CSS**, aunque esta se trate de un svg. Existen librerías de iconos externas, como **font-awesome** que si que te permiten hacer un cambio de color mediante **CSS** a los iconos que te ofrecen. Yo es lo que usaría para conseguir lo que deseas.

Comment: @PHPMyguel muchas gracias, he ido sacando conclusiones. Mirare a ver al final como lo hago y lo comentare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra alternativa es utilizar svg como data uri:

```css
.catalogo-gallery .btn-pdf
{
   font-size: 17px;
   font-weight: 800;
   font-family: "Open Sans"; 
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   padding: 12px 40px;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' %3E%3Ccircle r='50' cx='50' cy='50' fill='tomato'/%3E%3Ccircle r='41' cx='47' cy='50' fill='orange'/%3E%3Ccircle r='33' cx='48' cy='53' fill='gold'/%3E%3Ccircle r='25' cx='49' cy='51' fill='yellowgreen'/%3E%3Ccircle r='17' cx='52' cy='50' fill='lightseagreen'/%3E%3Ccircle r='9' cx='55' cy='48' fill='teal'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   background-size: 30px;
   background-position: 2px 8px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalogo-gallery">
  <a href="#" class="btn-pdf">Descargar PDF</a>
</div>
```

Lea más acerca de [SVG como data:uri](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/svg/utilizar-svg.php)

Answer (score 2):

A mí me resulta esto:

```css
.catalogo-gallery .btn-pdf
{
   font-size: 17px;
   font-weight: 800;
   font-family: "Open Sans";
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   padding: 12px 40px;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/337/337946.svg");
   background-size: 30px;
   background-position: 0 8px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalogo-gallery">
  <a href="#" class="btn-pdf">Descargar PDF</a>
</div>
```

No será problema de la ruta relativa de la imagen? Tal vez debieras probar poniendo la ruta absoluta respecto de tu dominio.

Comment: estoy usando wordpress, pero el svg no lo puedo subir a la biblioteca de medios por seguridad

Comment: tu solucion me ha ayudado bastante

Comment: Wordpress no permite SVGs porque si permites que otros usuarios suban SVGs, o tú subes uno sin revisarlo, éstos pueden contener javascript y ejecutarse sin más. Lee el artículo  [svg-in-wordpress](https://bjornjohansen.no/svg-in-wordpress). Por si acaso,  exixse el plugin [Safe SVG](https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-svg/) que permite subir SVGs y de paso los sanitiza. Pero quién sabe si esa sanitización es realmente a prueba de balas

Comment: Buenas al ginal lo subi por ftp al servidor directamente

Answer (score 1):

Por un lado: Puedes añadir una declaración al functions.php de tu tema en wordpress para que te permita subir svg a medios:

```
/*************************************************************************************************************************************
    Funcionalidad del tema > Añadir svg a media upload
*************************************************************************************************************************************/

function svg_myme_types($mime_types){
    $mime_types['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml'; //Adding svg extension
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'svg_myme_types', 1, 1);
```

Además de eso, puedes poner las imágenes en una carpeta images dentro de tu tema o tu child-theme, que es desde donde las buscará el css (sin que haga falta añadir más ruta que el nombre de la carpeta).

En este caso:

```
background-image: url("images/image.svg");
```